# localhost contact form not working?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

It saying i have a mistake and I've done everything right i hope. I'm using localhost for now.. may that be the problem? if not what is.

I get an error on this row

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$to = "Lennyperez@mail.com";
$subject = "add this";

mail ($to, $subject, $name);

?>


   <form action="submit.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
       <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sumitbtn" value="submit">
   </form>
```

Comment: so what do we have to guess the error you are getting?

Comment: it says $name = $_POST['name']; is undefined.

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)` to check what the contents of `$_POST` are

Comment: It is because the post is only set after you submit the form. See either of the `isset($_POST)` answers below.

Comment: Consult [`my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22716446/) if you haven't already. @user3472622

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of factors as to why you are having difficulties with your mail form.

- Check to see if [`mail()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is installed and properly configured on your system.
- Use additional [`headers()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php); one being a `From:` which is missing in your code, although **not mandatory**.
  Mail will still attempt to send, however it could end up being sent to SPAM or ignored.
- Use conditional statements for your submit button and `mail()` success, including checking if the field is left empty or not.

The following has been successfully tested, sent and received in my INBOX.

PHP

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $to = "email@example.com";

        $subject = "add this";
        $headers="From: $name <email@example.com>";

        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $name, $headers);

    if($sent) {

        echo "Success.";

       } else {
        echo 'Sorry, your message could not be sent.';
       }

    } // brace for submit conditional statement

?>
```

You can also use the following:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $from = "user@example.com";
        $to = "your@example.com";

        $subject = "add this";
        $headers="From: $name <$from>";

        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $name, $headers);

        if($sent) {

            echo "Success";

           } else {
            echo 'Sorry, your message could not be sent.';
           }
    } // brace for submit conditional statement

?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

- Check your server logs.

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` doesn't work on localhost without an external library.

Also, you need to do an `isset` on `$_POST['name'];`

```
if (isset($_POST)){
  $name    = $_POST['name'];
  $to      = "email@email.com";
  $subject = "this";

  mail ($to, $subject, $name);
}
```

Also don't forget to look at headers!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following: until the form is not submitted, the `$_POST['name']` variable is not set

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $to = "Lennyperez@mail.com";
    $subject = "add this";

    mail ($to, $subject, $name);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this work for you first:

```
<?php
mail("Lennyperez@mail.com", "add this", "name");
```

, and ask question again.

Answer (score 0):

When the page is loaded , it doesn't find post variables and that's normal because you have not clicked the submit button,your `$_POST['name']` will exist only after the submit button is pressed.

**Solution 1:**

Add a condition , mail will be sent only if a button submit is clicked.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $to = "Lennyperez@mail.com";
    $subject = "add this";

    mail ($to, $subject, $name);
}
?>
```

**Solution 2:**

Separate HTML file containing the form  from Your action page

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are receiving undefined notice if so please fallow one of these steps.

1. `Add @$name= $_POST['name'];`
   OR
2. `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`